# Setting unicode declaration in lxml.htm.clean.Cleaner or any other html2plaintext

Tags: python, unicode, lxml

How can I set the "Unicode strings encoding declaration" in the lxml.html.clean.Cleaner module?  I'm looking to read the plaintext of a website, and have used lxml in the past as a way of doing this, scraping out the html and javascript.  For some pages, I'm starting to get some weird errors about encoding, but can't make sense of how to set this param correctly [in the documentation](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.html.clean.Cleaner-class.html).

```
import requests
from lxml.html.clean import Cleaner

cleaner = Cleaner()
cleaner.javascript = True
cleaner.style = True
cleaner.html= True

>>> url = 'http://www.princeton.edu'
>>> r = requests.get(url)
>>> lx = r.text.replace('\t',' ').replace('\n',' ').replace('\r',' ')
>>> #lx = r.text
... lxclean = cleaner.clean_html(lx)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/home/username/gh/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/html/clean.py", line 501, in clean_html
    doc = fromstring(html)
  File "/home/username/gh/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 672, in fromstring
    doc = document_fromstring(html, parser=parser, base_url=base_url, **kw)
  File "/home/username/gh/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 568, in document_fromstring
    value = etree.fromstring(html, parser, **kw)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 2997, in lxml.etree.fromstring (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:63276)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1607, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:93592)
ValueError: Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported. Please use bytes input or XML fragments without declaration.
```

However, it works for other urls, like 'http://www.google.com'

Answer (score 0):

This seems suddenly broken.  Use beautifulsoup's html parser instead.